# Unable to typecast char to int.

Tags: c++, casting

I am a high school beginner to C++ (Less than 1 month since I started). I have been trying to convert a int into its char value. (So, a 5 should convert to a '5')

I am aware how to convert from char to int (from '5' to 5), by subtracting 48 from it, however I am unable to cast the other way. Here's what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    cout<<x<<endl;
    cout<<(char)x<<endl;
    cout<<static_cast<char>(x)<<endl;
    cout<<"end of program"<<endl;
}
```

The output I get is

```
5


end of program
```

I am unsure why I don't get an output. Appreciate any advice.

Comment: If you need to subtract `48` to get from `'5'` to `5`, what would you have to do to go the other way?

Comment: What should 14 convert to?

Comment: char is a number. Each number denotes to symbol in coding page. 5 is for ENQ. Try 65, for example. Ref. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: @user1217: Where did you get the idea that you need to "cast" it? You just said yourself that you had to "subtract 48" to get from `char` to `int`. Shouldn't that already make it obvious what you need to do in order to back to `char`? Yet instead you are trying to "cast" it for some reason... Why?

Comment: Don't subtract 48, subtract `'0'`. Don't make someone reading your code have to guess what the significance of 48 is. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants

Answer (score 2):

The cast is working perfectly fine (for what you're doing).

You're casting a `5` to it's ASCII value. Look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and see what a `5` represents.

Now for what you're trying to do, try `cout << (char)(x+48) << endl;`

Comment: Thanks so much! 5 translates 'ENQ' which doesn't print anything. Gotcha

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << ( char )( x + '0' ) << endl;
    cout << static_cast<char>( x + '0' ) < <endl;
    cout << "end of program" < <endl;
}
```

And you have not to look through ASCII table.:) Take into account that there is EBCDIC table. The code I showed does not depend on a coding table. The C++ Standard guarantees that all characters of digits follow each other starting from '0' to '9'.

Comment: +1 Just saw this on a `MATLAB` code earlier today, super useful trick indeed.